integrating OPA having external data calls with envoy
I am trying to integrate OPA with Envoy for authorization purposes. It works successfully with OPA without any external data calls, but I need to bundle my auth.rego file with a data.json file to fully utilize its functionality.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3.8"
services:
  envoy:
    build: ./compose/envoy
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./envoy.yaml:/config/envoy.yaml
    environment:
      - DEBUG_LEVEL=debug
      - SERVICE_NAME=app
      - SERVICE_PORT=80

  opa:
    build: ./opa
    volumes:
      - ./policy.rego:/config/policy.rego
      - ./data.json:/config/data.json
    environment:
      - DEBUG_LEVEL=debug
      - SERVICE_NAME=app
      - SERVICE_PORT=80

  app:
    build: ./app
    expose:
      - "80"

dockerfile for opa
# Use an official OPA image as the base
FROM ubuntu:latest as build-env
# Create a directory for bundling (adjust name if needed)
WORKDIR /opa-bundle

# Copy policy and data files to the working directory
COPY policy.rego data.json ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget

# Download OPA binary
RUN curl -L -o opa https://openpolicyagent.org/downloads/latest/opa_linux_amd64
RUN chmod +x opa
RUN cp opa /bin

# # Build the policy and data bundle
RUN opa build --bundle . -o /bundle.tar.gz

# # Create the final working directory for OPA

FROM openpolicyagent/opa:0.23.0-envoy
# # Copy the bundle to the final location
COPY  --from=build-env bundle.tar.gz /etc/opa/bundle.tar.gz

# # Run OPA in server mode with the required configuration
CMD ["opa","run", "--log-level=debug", "--server", "--set=plugins.envoy_ext_authz_grpc.addr=:9191", "--set=decision_logs.console=true", "/etc/opa"]


After building, I am getting "Error: unknown command "opa" for "opa_envoy_linux_amd64"" this error from opa image

Does the openpolicyagent/opa image declare an ENTRYPOINT ["opa"]?  In which case you wouldn't need opa at the start of CMD, and it could result in an error like that.  (Note that specific version of that image seems very old, looking at the Docker Hub page.)

I tried without the ‘opa’ also. Same result
